# Total Time difference(in millisecond) between rows with respect to column field

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, duration, calculation

I would like to do up a calculation of time differences/timedelta between rows of my vehicle monitoring system. I have a total of 700 thousand rows of data which includes field such as:

Index, Timestamp, Lat, Long, Vehicle Model

There are 7 different models in my data

As of now, I'm able to do the calculation of individual rows time difference by using the code as shown below:

```
 mydataset['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset["timestamp"], format = 
 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 mydataset['timedelta'] = (mydataset['timestamp'] - 
 mydataset['timestamp'].shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", 
 format="%H:%M:%S")))
```

With this code, I'm able to find the time differences. But right now, I want it to be filtered to each and every individual vehicle model. Right now, I am only capable to do calculation of the differences from each and every row. But some of the rows consist of different model. Is there any ways for me to let it "look at" vehicle model and do calculation?

e.g. of data

```
1,x,2018-05-16 09:14:37.343,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
2,x,2018-05-16 09:14:42.343,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
3,x,2018-05-16 09:14:47.343,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
4,x,2018-05-16 09:14:52.344,0 days 00:00:05.001000000
5,x,2018-05-16 09:14:57.344,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
6,y,2018-05-16 09:15:02.344,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
7,y,2018-05-16 09:15:07.344,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
8,y,2018-05-16 09:15:12.344,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
9,x,2018-05-16 09:15:17.344,0 days 00:00:05.000000000
10,x,2018-05-16 09:15:22.345,0 days 00:00:05.001000000
```

An update! As shown below is the code that helps me group the vehicle model. Would like to ask for the methods to total up each model's time difference!

```
mydataset['new'] = mydataset.groupby('Model').timestamp.diff()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `groupby` model and take the `diff()`

```
>>> df.groupby('model').timestamp.diff()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your prompt reply. So if i were to use this line of code, do i still need to use my code to do the time difference? Or i will have to use both?

Comment: Just make sure to have a column called timestamp that will hold the return of your `pd.to_datetime` above. Then run this line of code :)

Comment: Hi! I've tried using that line but the output is the exact same thing as before editted. :(

Comment: What do you mean? This can't yield the same value as before because you are grouping by the model , so it won't take the difference between two rows with different models. What you might be confused about is that this returns a New data frame. So `df` will not change. Or course you can save the return of this line of code in another variable and use it later on

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! I missed out some stuff therefore it was not reflected! But to "level up" this question. Is there anyways to add up the total duration difference of different model? I will update the question at the same time

Comment: Any method/solution to do a total duration per vehicle within this set of code? @piRSquared :)

Comment: @ThanksForHelping `df.groupby('AV ID').timestamp.apply(np.ptp)`

Comment: Hi @piRSquared I've include that into my code but it does not reflect anything! I tried to google on np.ptp but i dont really understand what it does. Could you explain the code above that you commented? Sorry for any inconvenience caused!!!!

Comment: `np.ptp` stands for **peak-to-peak**.  What it does is calculates the difference between the maximum and minimum values.  For you, this represents the total time.  Not sure what you meant by not reflected.  Do you not assign it to a name and look at it?

Comment: It returns a NaT in my new column.    I've inserted mydataset['newnew'] = mydataset.groupby('AV ID').timestamp.apply(np.ptp) . or did i do the wrong way?